# Problem sending 2 files to the client using Boost.Asio, Error: read: End of file [asio.misc:2]

Tags: boost, boost-asio, tcpclient, tcpserver, asio

I want to send two files to the client, the first file is img.jpg and the second file is message.txt

The first file img.jpg is received correctly, but the file message.txt is received with size zero

client output is:
img.jpg: 49152
message.txt: 4096
`read: End of file [asio.misc:2]`

here are my client and server codes:

server.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_context io;
        std::cout << "Server Start\n";
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acc(io,
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 6666));

        for (;;) {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io);
            acc.accept(sock);

            std::vector<std::string> names{ "img.jpg" , "message.txt"};
            std::vector<int> sizes{ 49152 , 4096 };

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
            
                //Send Header
                boost::asio::streambuf reply;
                std::ostream header(&reply);
                header << names[i] << " ";
                header << std::to_string(sizes[i]) << " ";
                header << "\r\n";
                boost::asio::write(sock, reply);

                //Send Bytes
                std::ifstream input(names[i], std::ifstream::binary);
                std::vector<char> vec(sizes[i]);
                input.read(&vec[i], sizes[i]);
                boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(vec, sizes[i]));
            }

            sock.close();
        }
        acc.close();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {

        boost::asio::io_context io;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolv(io);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query q("127.0.0.1", "6666");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator ep = resolv.resolve(q);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io);
        boost::asio::connect(sock, ep);

        //Get Files
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {

            //Read Header
            boost::asio::streambuf reply;
            boost::asio::read_until(sock, reply, "\r\n");
            std::istream header(&reply);
        
            std::string fileName;
            int fileSize;
            header >> fileName;
            header >> fileSize;
            std::cout << fileName << ": " << fileSize << '\n';
            //Read File Data
            std::ofstream output(fileName, std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::app);

            std::vector<char> vec(fileSize);
            boost::asio::read(sock, boost::asio::buffer(vec, vec.size()));

            output.write(&vec[0], vec.size());

            output.close();
        }

        sock.close();

    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

1. `&vec[i]` is a bug in the server side here:

   ```
   std::vector<char> vec(sizes[i]);
   input.read(&vec[i], sizes[i]);
   ```

   If `i>0` (which it always is except on the first run) you will address `vec` out-of-bounds because size is not `sizes[i]+i`
2. your header format is sloppy: filenames with spaces will cause [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
3. `os << to_string(n)` should just be `os << n`
4. server uses a delimiter `"\r\n"` that the client... completely ignores. All your files begin at least with `\r\n` that wasn't consumed, and what's worse, the last two characters of the file will then be read as part of the next file's header. This, at best, will fail, but can lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
5. In fact, it will always lead to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because there's a complete lack of error handling on the client side
6. I notice now that you ALMOST skirt the issue by using a separate buffer for the header (`streambuf header;`) and the contents (directly into `vec`). However, `read_until` documents that it may read past the delimiter¹. So, you should have written any remaining data from `streambuf` and subtract the length from the amount to still read.

   In short, recommend to use separate, exact size buffers **OR** one [`DynamicBuffer`](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/reference/DynamicBuffer.html) (like `streambuf`) per stream.
7. The same issue is with the client using a new buffer each iteration through the loop:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
       // Read Header
       asio::streambuf reply;
   ```

   It should at least be outside the loop so any excess data received will correctly be used on the next iteration
8. You usually want to deal with partial success of reads (i.e. accept data received together with EOF condition). Here it **should** not affect correctness because you are precisely limiting the body read to the expected size, but it is still a good habit
9. You specify redundant buffer size in `asio::buffer(vec, vec.size())`, this merely invites bugs. Leave them away to get the same behaviour without the risk of getting the wrong size: `asio::buffer(vec)` (e.g. it would avoid the UB mentioned earlier)

### Demonstrating The Buffer Issues

A combined server/client with halfway fixes: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03bee101ff6e8a7a

The client side adds a lot error handling

```
asio::streambuf buf;
for (;;) {
    asio::read_until(sock, buf, "\r\n");

    std::string name;
    int         size;
    if (std::istream header(&buf); (header >> std::quoted(name) >> size).ignore(1024, '\n')) {
        std::cout << name << ": " << size << '\n';

        std::vector<char> vec(size);
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        auto n = read(sock, asio::buffer(vec), ec);

        if (n != vec.size()) {
            std::cerr << "Read completed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Incomplete data (" << n << " of " << vec.size() << ")" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Streambuf still had " << buf.size() << " bytes (total: " << (n + buf.size()) << ")" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        std::ofstream(name, std::ios::binary /*| std::ios::app*/).write(&vec[0], n);
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error receiving header, header invalid?" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

This allows us to demonstrate the problem with the `streambuf` reading beyond the delimiter:

```
main.cpp: 2712
main.cpp: 2712
Read completed: End of file
Incomplete data (2217 of 2712)
Streambuf still had 495 bytes (total: 2712)
```

Or my local test:

```
test.gif: 400557
message.txt: 4096
Incomplete data (3604 of 4096)
Streambuf still had 492 (total: 4096)
```

The clunky/naive way to fix might seem to be something like:

```
if (std::istream header(&buf); (header >> std::quoted(name) >> size).ignore(1024, '\n')) {
    std::cout << name << ": " << size << '\n';

    std::cerr << "Streambuf still had " << buf.size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
    size -= buf.size();
    std::ofstream ofs(name, std::ios::binary /*| std::ios::app*/);
    ofs << &buf;

    std::cerr << "Adjusted size to read: " << size << std::endl;

    std::vector<char> vec(size);
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto n = read(sock, asio::buffer(vec), ec);

    if (n != vec.size()) {
        std::cerr << "Read completed: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Incomplete data (" << n << " of " << vec.size() << ")" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    ofs.write(&vec[0], n);
} else {
    std::cerr << "Error receiving header, header invalid?" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

And while it **might** appear to work correctly:

[image]

It just invites new problems with small files, where the entire following files are "accidentally" used as the contents for the current file. Instead, just SayWhatYouMean(TM):

```
if ((std::istream(&buf) >> name >> size).ignore(1024, '\n')) {
    std::cout << name << ": " << size << '\n';

    read(sock, buf, asio::transfer_exactly(size), ec);

    if (buf.size() < size) {
        std::cerr << "Incomplete data" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    std::ofstream(output_dir / name, std::ios::binary /*| std::ios::app*/)
        .write(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data()), size);

    buf.consume(size);
} else {
```

### Full Fixes

Also getting a file list from the command line instead of hardcoding files/sizes, and writing to an output directory for safety.

Note that it now uses `std::filesystem::path` wich **already** uses `std::quoted` under the hood to protect against problems with filenames with spaces: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40de665584aa1cbd)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using std::ranges::contains;
using std::filesystem::path;
constexpr uint16_t PORT = 6666;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) try {
    asio::io_context io;

    std::vector<std::string_view> const
        args(argv + 1, argv + argc), 
        opts{"--client", "-c", "--server", "-s"};

    bool const server = contains(args, "--server") || contains(args, "-s");
    bool const client = contains(args, "--client") || contains(args, "-c");

    if (server) {
        std::cout << "Server Start" << std::endl;

        for (tcp::acceptor acc(io, {{}, PORT});;) {
            tcp::socket sock = acc.accept();

            for (path name : args) {
                if (contains(opts, name))
                    continue;
                auto size = file_size(name);

                // Send Header
                asio::streambuf buf;
                std::ostream(&buf) << name << " " << size << "\r\n";
                write(sock, buf);

                // Send bytes
                std::vector<char> vec(size);
                std::ifstream(name, std::ios::binary).read(vec.data(), size);
                write(sock, asio::buffer(vec));
            }
        }
    }

    if (client) {
        path output_dir = "./output/";
        create_directories(output_dir);

        tcp::socket sock(io);
        // connect(sock, tcp::resolver(io).resolve("127.0.0.1", std::to_string(PORT)));
        sock.connect({{}, PORT});

        asio::streambuf buf;

        for (boost::system::error_code ec;;) {
            read_until(sock, buf, "\r\n", ec);

            path   name;
            size_t size;
            if ((std::istream(&buf) >> name >> size).ignore(1024, '\n')) {
                std::cout << name << ": " << size << '\n';

                read(sock, buf, asio::transfer_exactly(size), ec);

                if (buf.size() < size) {
                    std::cerr << "Incomplete data" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                std::ofstream(output_dir / name, std::ios::binary /*| std::ios::app*/)
                    .write(buffer_cast<char const*>(buf.data()), size);

                buf.consume(size);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error receiving header, header invalid?" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

With the live test of

```
for a in {1..10}; do dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=10 of=small-$a.txt; done 2>/dev/null
g++ -std=c++2b -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
./a.out --server *.* &
sleep 1; ./a.out --client
kill %1
md5sum {.,output}/*.* | sort
```

Printed:

```
Server Start
"a.out": 187496
"main.cpp": 2546
"small-1.txt": 10
"small-10.txt": 10
"small-2.txt": 10
"small-3.txt": 10
"small-4.txt": 10
"small-5.txt": 10
"small-6.txt": 10
"small-7.txt": 10
"small-8.txt": 10
"small-9.txt": 10
Error receiving header, header invalid?
024c40ee2e93ee2e6338567336094ba2  ./small-8.txt
024c40ee2e93ee2e6338567336094ba2  output/small-8.txt
164f873a00178eca1354b1a4a398bf0f  ./small-10.txt
164f873a00178eca1354b1a4a398bf0f  output/small-10.txt
2ff416d02ca7ea8db2b5cb489a63852d  ./small-6.txt
2ff416d02ca7ea8db2b5cb489a63852d  output/small-6.txt
4559b8844afe7d5090948e97a8cef8d8  ./small-7.txt
4559b8844afe7d5090948e97a8cef8d8  output/small-7.txt
6fd6eac47427bfda3fc5456afed99602  ./small-4.txt
6fd6eac47427bfda3fc5456afed99602  output/small-4.txt
76fa51d5d6f06b9c8483f5539cd5611b  ./a.out
76fa51d5d6f06b9c8483f5539cd5611b  output/a.out
8a114a62f0ad5e087d7b338eeebcadf1  ./small-1.txt
8a114a62f0ad5e087d7b338eeebcadf1  output/small-1.txt
b4f11b6ed8870d431c5ec579d12991c0  ./small-5.txt
b4f11b6ed8870d431c5ec579d12991c0  output/small-5.txt
e1f0f06f1226ff7c82f942684d22e100  ./small-3.txt
e1f0f06f1226ff7c82f942684d22e100  output/small-3.txt
ec3fabd7edd0870bcfa5bbcfc7f2c7ec  ./small-2.txt
ec3fabd7edd0870bcfa5bbcfc7f2c7ec  output/small-2.txt
f80c5bbe46af5f46e4d4bcb2b939bf38  ./main.cpp
f80c5bbe46af5f46e4d4bcb2b939bf38  output/main.cpp
ff225cbc0f536f8af6946261c4a6b3ec  ./small-9.txt
ff225cbc0f536f8af6946261c4a6b3ec  output/small-9.txt
```

### BONUS

Instead of doing text-based IO, consider sending binary file size and name information. See for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20endian%20file&searchOn=3

**UPDATE**: Turns out bonus take removes ALL the complexity: no more streambuf, unbounded reads, partial success, parsing, error handling.

Given

```
using NetSize = boost::endian::big_uint64_t;
using Header  = std::array<NetSize, 2>;
```

You can now send evrything in one go:

```
for (path name : args) {
    if (contains(opts, name))
        continue;

    std::ifstream     ifs(name, std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<char> vec(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});

    auto   namestr = name.native();
    Header header{namestr.size(), vec.size()};

    write(sock,
          std::array{
              asio::buffer(header),
              asio::buffer(namestr),
              asio::buffer(vec),
          });
}
```

And on the receiving side:

```
for (std::string name, data;;) {
    Header header;
    read(sock, asio::buffer(header));

    auto [namelen, datalen] = header;
    name.resize(namelen);
    data.resize(datalen);

    read(sock, std::array{asio::buffer(name), asio::buffer(data)});

    std::ofstream(output_dir / name, std::ios::binary /*| std::ios::app*/) << data;
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305671601b21b41e)**

---

¹ because of how TCP packet delivery works; this is how all libraries behave

Comment: Took the time after dinner to add the "BONUS" take. It's much much simpler: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305671601b21b41e)**. No more streambufs, text parsing, error handling, conditional stuff due to unbounded reads. Just, straight ahead

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and complete explanation, I realized that the problem is due to the use of streambuf and vector, and I solved the problem of sending the file by changing the buffers, but there are some points that I will raise below and please explain them.

Comment: about issue #4 When we use read_until, does it also put the delimiter "\r\n" in the buffer? Or will the delimiter be saved in the buffer in the next call?

Comment: Regarding issue #5, for now, if I can write a code that works correctly, that's great, I'll add error handling later :)

Comment: about issue #9: Why is it risky to add vector size?

Comment: #9 Because it's possible to have the wrong size (much like the actual bug you had in the live before that)

Comment: #4 of course: it's impossible to detect the delimiter before it has been received. In genera [any ·MatchCondition· operates on the full contents of the buffer between composed read operations](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html)

Comment: I hope you see the irony of #5 in the sense that you were here :) or even better, I hope that the reverse illustration of tracing expected values (under **Demonstrating The Buffer Issues**) shows how it helps understanding. In your code it was impossible to have correct operation without at least rid handling. Also, I'll have you know I needed to check my assumptions and test with many sizes of files before I got everything right in the text-header version of the code. It's just a good habit of programmers _in order to get it right in the first place_

Comment: You are great, I enjoy your detailed answers. I will practice the methods you explained and the way you write code several times so that I can implement these tips in the programs I write.